# Emissive textures in Ursina?

Tags: python, textures, ursina

I downloaded a 3D model off the internet for my Ursina game project. It comes with a base texture, along with an emissive texture file.

In Ursina, is there a way to use the base texture for an entity and make it "glow" using the emissive map?

Note: I've tried using texture=("/base_texture.png", "/emissive_texture") but it didn't work